# Why does sorted "tan" != "ant"?

Tags: string, sorting, go

I'm trying to sort the characters in a string by sorting a slice of the bytes in the string (using sort.Slice). The code I'm using gets the right results sometimes but other times produces results I can't make sense of.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    for _, s := range []string{"nat", "tan", "ant"} {
        b := []byte(s)
        sort.Slice(b, func(i int, j int) bool { return s[i] < s[j] })
        fmt.Println(s, string(b))
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/bC9QWq7aF3G

I would expect "nat", "tan" and "ant" to all be sorted to "ant", but "tan" is sorted to "atn".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `sort.Slice` line to:

```
sort.Slice(b, func(i int, j int) bool { return b[i] < b[j] })
```

`sort.Slice` needs your `less` function to compare values in the slice in order to sort the way you intended.  Your bug is that you used `s` rather than `b` in your `less` function.